# iOS FBRequest success delegate method

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there any simple way to get a success notification from instance of `FBRequest`?

Like `- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the only way is to check if response code of NSURLResponse is 200.

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    if (200 == [response statusCode]) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }    
}
```